# Hibernate fetching quick if setMaxResults is set

Tags: oracle, performance, hibernate, fetch

There is a simple sql query which fetches **only ONE** record. The database is oracle.

Following is the simple query:

```
select *
from APPEALCASE appealcase0_
where appealcase0_.caseNumber='BAXXXXX00' and appealcase0_.DELETED_FLAG='N'
```

When I fetch this row using hibernate the response time is `500ms` which is slow since it has to be really quick and withing 10ms. But when I set the `MaxResults` in the hibernate query object to 1(one) the response time improved to 15ms. 
Though my issue is fixed I'm still puzzled how setting `MaxResults` to 1 improved the response time drastically. Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: Is the slow response time visible only when using Hibernate -- or this appends too when issuing the same query from SQL*Plus ?

Comment: It happens only when the query runs through a jdbc connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's quite logical to me. Since you tell Oracle to retrieve at most one record, it stops searching for more as soon as it finds one. Whereas if you don't, it scans the whole table (or index) to find all the records matching the search criteria.

What you should check, though, is if you have an index defined on the `caseNumber` column.

Comment: Yes I do have a index on the column and even after that I need to set MaxResults to one to get a good response. I suppose the query.FetchSize to 1 should have improved the performance rather the MaxResults api did the magic.